# I am not able to create a feature store in vertexAI using labels

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am passing the values of lables as below to create a featurestore with labels. But after creation of the featurestore, I do not see the featurestore created with labels. Is it still not supported in VertexAI

```py
    fs = aiplatform.Featurestore.create(
        featurestore_id=featurestore_id,
        labels=dict(project='retail', env='prod'),
        online_store_fixed_node_count=online_store_fixed_node_count,
        sync=sync
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [featurestore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/managing-featurestores):

> A **featurestore** is a top-level container for entity types, features,
> and feature values.

With this, the GCP console UI "labels" are the "labels" at the **Feature** level.

Once a **featurestore** is created, you will need to create an **entity** and then create a **Feature** that has the *labels* parameter as shown on the below sample python code.

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform

test_label = {'key1' : 'value1'}

def create_feature_sample(
    project: str,
    location: str,
    feature_id: str,
    value_type: str,
    entity_type_id: str,
    featurestore_id: str,
):

    aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location)

    my_feature = aiplatform.Feature.create(
        feature_id=feature_id,
        value_type=value_type,
        entity_type_name=entity_type_id,
        featurestore_id=featurestore_id,
        labels=test_label,
    )

    my_feature.wait()

    return my_feature

create_feature_sample('your-project','us-central1','test_feature3','STRING','test_entity3','test_fs3')
```

Below is the screenshot of the GCP console which shows that *labels* for **test_feature3** feature has the values defined in the above sample python code.
[image]

You may refer to this [creation of feature documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/managing-features#create-feature) using python for more details.

On the other hand, you may still view the *labels* you defined for your featurestore using the REST API as shown on the below sample.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
"https://<your-location>-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project>/locations/<your-location>/featurestores"
```

Below is the result of the REST API which also shows the value of the *labels* I defined for my "test_fs3" featurestore.
[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, although I was able to add labels following the above code. But the label information did not flow to bigquery through billing export.

Comment: For your follow-up question, since this is related to billing export (to BigQuery) question, I suggest to post it as a new question with the complete details, step you've done and screenshots (if applicable) for more focused question with enough details for the community to answer.